Python web scraping w/BeatifulSoup
I'm pretty new to Python, but like to learn new stuff.
I want to create a Python script to return the return tariff for the electricity, this value I want to feed into my home automation system (openHAB) and when the return is a negative value, I will shut off my solar panels.
My electricity company has some kind of web XML API where you can obtain these values by adding the date/time as a parameter in the URL, this is all working, but I can't figure out how to scrap the exact return tariff number because it ain't a separate tag in the file. This is what I came up to so far:
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import datetime

currentT = datetime.datetime.now()

url = 'https://mijn.easyenergy.com/nl/api/tariff/getapxtariffs?startTimestamp='+currentT.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')+'T'+currentT.strftime("%H")+'%3A00%3A00.000Z&endTimestamp='+currentT.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')+'T'+currentT.strftime("%H")+'%3A59%3A00.000Z'
response = requests.get(url, verify=False)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, features="lxml")

for tag in soup('p'):
    print(tag)

This is the current URL it is using now:

https://mijn.easyenergy.com/nl/api/tariff/getapxtariffs?startTimestamp=2024-04-02T14%3A00%3A00.000Z&endTimestamp=2024-04-02T14%3A59%3A00.000Z

it returns this data if you print the soup:
<html><body><p>[{"Timestamp":"2024-04-02T14:00:00+00:00","SupplierId":0,"TariffUsage":0.005215100000000000,"TariffReturn":0.00431}]</p></body></html>

So all data is in tag P but I'm only interested in the number after: TariffReturn
How should I proceed from here to get this data?

why are you using beautifulsoup if the endpoint returns xml data?
import requests
response = requests.get("your url")
print(response.json()[0].get("TariffReturn"))


Good question, well, I went online and ended up on some YT videos claiming that bs4 is the best and easiest way is to scrape XML and HTML, that's why I choice that route. But thanks, that works! Just out of curiosity, would it also be possible with bs4?

honestly, no clue

Concerning to your question you have to load JSON module and convert the string into JSON json.loads(soup.get_text())[0].get("TariffReturn"), but better go with direct use as shown in the answer.

haha thanks anyway, this seems a lot cleaner solution. Like you understand, I wasn't aware this was possible, will look into it what else is possible, guess it will be a good solution in future projects

if
<html><body><p>[{"Timestamp":"2024-04-02T14:00:00+00:00","SupplierId":0,"TariffUsage":0.005215100000000000,"TariffReturn":0.00431}]</p></body></html>

is your Input you can do the following:
import re

CLEANR = re.compile('<.*?>') 

def cleanhtml(raw_html):
  cleantext = re.sub(CLEANR, '', raw_html)
  return cleantext

With this regex you will clean away all the tags.
in the next step you can save the rest which is:
data =  {"Timestamp":"2024-04-02T14:00:00+00:00","SupplierId":0,"TariffUsage":0.005215100000000000,"TariffReturn":0.00431}

This is basically a dict in python, you can read TariffReturn by
data['TariffReturn']

Result:
0.00431


The fact that the output contains HTML is due to the previous conversion to a beautifulsoup object.

Thanks for the quick reply, just wondering, how would I store obtained data as html so it can be recompiled?
